# Error installing Aubio with Python/pip on Windows

Tags: python, pip, aubio

### Problem

I ran `pip install aubio`, here are the errors:

```
Collecting aubio
  Downloading aubio-0.4.9.tar.gz (479 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 479.0/479.0 kB 4.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\izywy\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from aubio) (1.24.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: aubio
  Building wheel for aubio (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [32 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\aubio
      copying python\lib\aubio\cmd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\aubio
      copying python\lib\aubio\cut.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\aubio
      copying python\lib\aubio\midiconv.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\aubio
      copying python\lib\aubio\slicing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\aubio
      copying python\lib\aubio\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\aubio
      running build_ext
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      checking for aubio = 0.4.9
      Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags aubio = 0.4.9" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
      Info: aubio 0.4.9 was not found by pkg-config
      Info: looking for *optional* additional packages
      checking for libavcodec
      Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags libavcodec" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
      checking for libavformat
      Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags libavformat" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
      checking for libavutil
      Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags libavutil" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
      checking for libswresample
      Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags libswresample" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
      checking for libavresample
      Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags libavresample" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
      checking for sndfile
      Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags sndfile" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
      checking for samplerate
      Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags samplerate" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
      Info: libaubio was not installed or built locally with waf, adding src/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for aubio
  Running setup.py clean for aubio
Failed to build aubio
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aubio, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

C:\Users\izywy>pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\izywy\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (23.2.1)

C:\Users\izywy>pip install --upgrade wheel
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in c:\users\izywy\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (0.40.0)
Collecting wheel
  Obtaining dependency information for wheel from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/28/f5/6955d7b3a5d71ce6bac104f9cf98c1b0513ad656cdaca8ea7d579196f771/wheel-0.41.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Downloading wheel-0.41.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
Downloading wheel-0.41.1-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 64.8/64.8 kB 1.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: wheel
  Attempting uninstall: wheel
    Found existing installation: wheel 0.40.0
    Uninstalling wheel-0.40.0:
      Successfully uninstalled wheel-0.40.0
Successfully installed wheel-0.41.1

C:\Users\izywy>pip install aubio
Collecting aubio
  Using cached aubio-0.4.9.tar.gz (479 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\izywy\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from aubio) (1.24.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: aubio
  Building wheel for aubio (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [32 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\aubio
      copying python\lib\aubio\cmd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\aubio
      copying python\lib\aubio\cut.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\aubio
      copying python\lib\aubio\midiconv.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\aubio
      copying python\lib\aubio\slicing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\aubio
      copying python\lib\aubio\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\aubio
      running build_ext
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      checking for aubio = 0.4.9
      Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags aubio = 0.4.9" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
      Info: aubio 0.4.9 was not found by pkg-config
      Info: looking for *optional* additional packages
      checking for libavcodec
      Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags libavcodec" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
      checking for libavformat
      Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags libavformat" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
      checking for libavutil
      Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags libavutil" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
      checking for libswresample
      Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags libswresample" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
      checking for libavresample
      Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags libavresample" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
      checking for sndfile
      Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags sndfile" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
      checking for samplerate
      Running "pkg-config --libs --cflags samplerate" failed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
      Info: libaubio was not installed or built locally with waf, adding src/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for aubio
  Running setup.py clean for aubio
Failed to build aubio
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aubio, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I was installing some other libraries earlier without any problems, why could this happen?

### Specifications

**OS**: Windows 11
**Python Version**:  3.10

Comment: The relevant part of that output is `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/`

Comment: https://aubio.org/manual/latest/python_module.html , https://aubio.org/manual/latest/installing.html

Comment: that didn't work...